# Resharper: Unit of measure is redundant

Tags: css, visual-studio

Resharper complain if you have code like this:

```
border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
```

and insists that units should be removed from zeroes as they are redundant. They are redundant, that is absolutely true, but I don't like inconsistency that is introduced by removal of units. You get code like this

```
border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
```

which is pretty hideous in my opinion. So, what do you guys think? Should I remove redundant units, or should I disable this warning?

Answer (score 6):

0cm, 0px or 0x corresponding to 0, it doesn't need unit if it's of the same order of magnitude. 0px * 10cm is the same than 0 * 10cm.
In this case border-width corresponding to length's order of magnitude it's not necessary to precise the units.

Moreover, for my part, I never specifies the things which are default. Whatever the language. I think it's more readable and elegant. It's my opinion because some people I met prefers specify everything.

I hope my english is not so bad .